# Не устанавливается роль для хостинга на сервере

Tags: asp.net, iis

Необходим компонент asp.net 4.5 для приложений.
Однако, ни через wpilouncher, ни через стандартные средства диспетчера сервера не устанавливается

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашлось несколько способов решения на просторах интернета, кто то предложил удалить службу которая мешала, кто то предложил качнуть оригинальный образ с мсдн и командой рестор из под командной строки восстановить
не помогло
помогла полностью новая установка.
Делайте бэкапы и все будет ОК